# How do I tell what is in solr index?

Tags: mysql, solr, indexing

I'm trying to index a very small (6 rows) table into solr, and it says that it's added/updated 6 documents, but it doesn't return anything when I search for a field. My table is as follows

```
League:
field      |  type  |
---------------------
id         |  int   |
leaguename |  string|
```

and here is what solr prints when I try to do the full-import

```
    03data-config.xmlfull-importidle1602011-07-13 19:11:42Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 6 documents. Deleted 0 documents.
2011-07-13 19:11:422011-07-13 19:11:4260:0:0.120
This response format is experimental. It is likely to change in the future.
```

Is there a way that I can view the values that index is holding? I've tried looking in the data folder in solr, but all the files just seem to have strange non-alphanumeric characters in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you ar erunning solr on localhost and port 8983 as per standard example
you can do a wildcard query like

http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=*:*

This will return all the documents with all stored fields.

Comment: Hey this worked perfectly. It seems that all the values are indeed being indexed correctly, but somehow searching for any of the individual strings, like "NBA" returns zero results, despite this   "<doc>
<str name="id">10</str>
<str name="leaguename">NBA</str>
</doc>"    appearing in the results for *:*     Any ideas?

Comment: You can have Solr "explain" the query to you and tell you why it matched what it did match and how. Basically just append "debugQuery=on" - more info here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#Debugging

Comment: I just tried setting that, and solr recognized it, but it's still not printing any 'explain' stuff. I can only get search results by querying *:*. Might that be why?

Comment: I fixed it. Had to change the defaultSearchIndex value to leaguename and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Luke is a desktop app which allows you to examine an index, run queries and generally muck around.

If the index is remote you will first need to transfer it to your desktop, then just open it in Luke.

http://code.google.com/p/luke/

Luke rocks!

Answer (score 1):

From the admin screen query a wildcard on whatever your unique key field is.

Uniquekeyfieldname:*
That will get you a count to see if something got indexed. If you want to see all fields too then specify the field list at the end of the query strong

&FL=*